# Two simultaneous rollbacks deadlocking tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

Accidentally the same stored procedure was run twice at one time on our MS SQL Server 2008 R2. They were run from the same SQL Server Management Studio client and I tried to cancel them both. After 45 minutes neither process has cancelled. I read somewhere that it would help to close the query windows in SSMS so I did. However the tables the stored procedure should be writing to is still locked even though almost 20 hours has passed. I guess there is a deadlock. I hit cancel seconds after the stored procedure was initiated.

The table the stored procedure is reading from is not locked. The stored procedure is in CLR. It reads from a table, manipulate data and then use SqlBulkCopy to insert into three other tables.

The data in the tables the SP writes to can very easily be recreated. However I can neither drop nor truncate them due to the lock. I also tried KILL SPID with no result.

I have been thinking about restarting the server, but I guess it would not help because of SQL Servers data integrity.

I would really like some input on how release the lock. Several websites with lots of users depend on the database server so solutions that do not involve restarting would be much appreciated.

Comment: What state are the relevant spids in?

Comment: Not sure if SQL CLR can be cancelled when in the middle of CLR code. Killing sqlservr.exe might actually help here. This will cause a physical rollback at server start.

Comment: The state of the spids are runnable. It sounds to me like they are dead, but the locks still holds.

Comment: Killing sqlservr.exe, is what shutting down the server? If there is any way around that, I would really like it.

Comment: @rlt killing does not harm the data in any way. It just kills running transactions and connections and requires a more lengthy startup. If this is a dev server, or if the server is unused at night, no problem. You can also execute `SHUTDOWN` for an orderly shutdown.

Comment: To solve the problem I created three new tables and used them instead of the locked tables. Several hours after posting this question the lock was lifted. I dropped the old tables and renamed the new tables to the original names. It might not exactly be a pretty solution, but it did get the job done without stopping the server.